# pyparsing precedence splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

In most examples that I can find precedence uses grouped (oneOf) literals to set the same level. With this approach I would have to look up which of the 2 (or more) it is and then continue with evaluation. What I would like to do is split the operators to directly know which one it is and evaluate it.

This is what I would like to implement, but the precedence levels are now wrong

```
arith_prec = [
    (subtract_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, ast.Substraction),
    (add_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, ast.Addition),
    (divide_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, ast.Division),
    (multiplication_op, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, ast.Multiplication),
]
```

This is what I had before but had to match which of the two (or more) it was

```
plusop = oneOf(['+', '-'])
multop = oneOf(['*', '/'])
arith_prec = [
    (plusop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
    (multop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
]
```

Is there a way of doing this? I have tested with using oneOf and Or inside of the arith_prec but to no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to match the operators within your parse action/class. Note that you will potentially get several operations, not just one with two operands. For instance, parsing "1 - 3 + 2" will give you `[1, '-', 3, '+', 2]`, so you really can't have this create an Addition or Subtraction class.

Perhaps combine them to classes like AddSub and MultDiv, which will iterate left-to-right through the parsed values to evaluate the value:

```
class BinOp:
    operator_map = {}

    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens

    def eval(self):
        seq = self.tokens
        ret = seq[0]
        for operator, operand in zip(seq[1::2], seq[2::2]):
            ret = self.operator_map[operator](ret, operand)
        return ret

class AddSub(BinOp):
    operator_map = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub}

class MultDiv(BinOp):
    operator_map = {'*': operator.mul, '/': operator.truediv}

plusop = oneOf(AddSub.operator_map.keys())
multop = oneOf(MultDiv.operator_map.keys())
arith_prec = [
    (multop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, MultDiv),
    (plusop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, AddSub),
]
```

Or broaden your concept of "addition" to include '+' and '-' operations. (As in engineering school, we had to generalize the concept of "acceleration" to include any change in velocity, either up or down.)

In any event, if you are using the `infixNotation` method, you will have to have each level of precedence include all the operators at that level.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll just have to go back to where I started and continue from there.

Comment: Btw, your precedence of operations is backwards - `multop` should go first.